# Cannot query the value of property 'applicationId' because configuration of project ':presentation' has not completed yet

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've just updated my android studio to android studio arctic fox and also I've updated some of my plugins. I also updated Gradle to Gradle 7.0 in the middle of Gradle building , I faced this error. I tried some solutions like adding or removing applicationId in my presentation gradle module and also in my conductor but none of them helped. I tried the solution said that applicationId have to be exactly the same in manifest file package name but It didn't work out.I'm sharing my `presentation` and `conductor` gradle module so If it needs more to be shared please tell me.
So what should I do now ?

**Presentation gradle module:**

```
plugins {
id ("com.android.library")
id ("kotlin-android")
id ("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion (30)
    buildToolsVersion ("30.0.2")

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion (19)
    targetSdkVersion (30)

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
}

buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        this.isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles (getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
}
//dependencies
```

**Conductor(App) gradle module:**

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("kotlin-android")
this.kotlin("kapt")
//    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    buildToolsVersion ("30.0.2")

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "ir.raamaan"
    minSdkVersion (19)
    targetSdkVersion (30)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        this.isMinifyEnabled = true
        proguardFiles (getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
}
```

Comment: I switched to an older branch and had a similar error message. It turned out that I was using an outdated version of Kotlin. So if anybody else is getting this kind of error, check if your Kotlin version needs to be updated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error goes away with Android Gradle Plugin Version **7.1.0-alpha05**.

```
Open File>Project Structure>Project & Update your version.


Alternatively,
//In your Top-level build file, update this in your dependencies section 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha05'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Interestingly it regresses again in `7.1.0-alpha06` so be careful! I guess that's what "alpha" means :)

Comment: Thanks! And I can confirm that `7.1.0-alpha06` breaks it again!

Comment: Matching the IDE kotlin version with project's version fixed the issue for me. Using 7.3.0-alpha06

Comment: Android Studio became so ladden with mysteries these days! But anyways, even merely reverting my project's gradle plugin to 7.1.0 did magically fix the issue for me! Thanks

Answer (score 20):

I got this same error while upgrading gradle:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4 --> 7.2.1
```

And the solution that worked for me was to update the kotlin-gradle-plugin (I had to solve sintax errors after this like the exhaustive "when" error):

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.7 --> 1.7.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Worked when Android Gradle Plugin Version was downgraded to ***7.1.3***

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
```

Comment: Yes. 7.1.3 is the last working version for me. 7.2.*, 7.3.0, and 7.3.1 are broken for me.