# Why I'm getting "Cannot query the value of property 'namespace' because configuration of project ':app' has not completed yet" after gradle upgrade?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

[image]I was trying to upgrade gradle from 6.5.1 to 7.3.3 but I am getting this error message

"Cannot query the value of property 'namespace' because configuration of project ':app' has not completed yet"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot query the value of property 'applicationId' because configuration of project ':presentation' has not completed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68588699/cannot-query-the-value-of-property-applicationid-because-configuration-of-proj)

Comment: I tried the two answers but nothing works!!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this after upgrading gradle:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.5.1 --> 7.3.3
```

Solution: Updgrade your kotlin gradle plugin

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin: --> latest version
```